# Django ORM: How to query for the latest row based on a another attribute

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have a table:

```
product_id  |  sales_rank  |  updated_on
1           |  572         |  2015-12-17 15:19:41
2           |  1000        |  2015-12-17 15:19:42
1           |  500         |  2015-12-18 15:19:41
2           |  1659        |  2015-12-18 15:19:42
```

I'm interested in making a query where I only select the last two rows from this table in Django ORM.

I want the latest updated rows from all unique product ID's.  How can I accomplish this?

Here is the dirty (and expensive) way I am doing it now:

```
sorted(Product.objects.distinct("product_id"), key=operator.attrgetter('sales_rank'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

```
from django.db.models import Max
Product.objects.values('product_id').annotate(latest=Max('updated_on'))
```

Comment: This is good, but how can I make this return ORM?  I want to then apply some filters to the return set.

Comment: You can apply the filter beforehand then do `values`. If you need other fields, you can do `values('product_id', 'sales_rank', 'random_field')` afterwards.